# Exception PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a column `topic` in the table `abonnement` when `id_abonnement=3`. For this, I want to make an exception when `id_abonnement=3` is not exist in database.

I'm trying something like that :

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            update abonnement set topic = 'valeurTopic' where id_abonnement = 3;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN "verification of id" THEN RAISE NOTICE 'id=3 not exist';
        END;
    END;
$$
```

Any solution please ?!

Comment: i can't create another table! i must to use one table and verify that as i explain

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution. It's simply like that :

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM abonnement WHERE id_abonnement=3) 
          THEN
             UPDATE abonnement set topic= 'valeurTopic' WHERE id_abonnement = 3;
             RAISE NOTICE 'good operation';
        ELSE
          RAISE NOTICE 'id = 3 not exist';
        END IF;
    END;
END;
```

$$